# Serialize object with umlauts to json file with Marshmallow

Tags: python, marshmallow

I want to serialize a pyhthon object to json. The object has some strings with umlauts in it. I use Marshmallow for the Schema. Below a code snippet.

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, post_load, post_dump
import logging as log
import os.path
log.basicConfig(level=log.DEBUG)

class Umlaut():
    def __init__(self, name): self.name = name

class UmlautSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    
    @post_dump
    def post_dump(self, data, many=False):
        log.debug(data) # Umlauts are fine
        return data

class Filehandling():
    def write(self, u):
        pathToFile = os.path.abspath("/tmp/")
        schema = UmlautSchema()
        res = schema.dumps(u)
        log.debug(res)  # Here we have 'Umlaut-\u00f6-\u00e4-\u00fc-\u00c4-\u00d6-\u00dc'
        file = os.path.join(pathToFile, "umlauts.json")
        with open(file, mode="w", encoding="UTF-8") as outfile:
            outfile.write(res)
            outfile.close()

def run():
    filehandling = Filehandling()
    u = Umlaut("Umlaut-ö-ä-ü-Ä-Ö-Ü")
    log.debug(u.name) # Umlauts are fine
    filehandling.write(u)
```

When I run my code the umlauts in the json file looks like \u00f6. What can I do to get the umlauts properly encoded like 'ä, ö, ü'?

When you look at the log statements in the post_dump method the umlauts are ok but when

Thanks for your help
Stephan

Comment: What's the purpose of the `Umlaut` class in the first place?

Comment: It is the same data, just encoded. `json` module defaults to `ensure_ascii=True`. Not sure how to configure it for `marshmallow`, sorry.

Comment: Found it: [Docs](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/marshmallow/schema.html#Schema.dumps) say that additional kwargs are passed to the json module configured, so for the default python `json` just use `schema.dumps(u, ensure_ascii=False)`

Comment: @ivvija Thanks for your answer. I know it is the same data. When I deserialize it from json to my object the umlauts look fine. But I want a "human readable" json so I can edit it by hand.

Comment: @ivvija That's it! The `schema.dumps(u, ensure_ascii=False)` did it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/marshmallow/schema.html#Schema.dumps) additional kwargs are passed to the configured JSON renderer, by default `json` from Python itself is used ([ref](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_reference.html#marshmallow.Schema.Meta)).

Using your classes with [`ensure_ascii=False`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump):

```
>>> schema.dumps(u, ensure_ascii=False)
'{"name": "Umlaut-ö-ä-ü-Ä-Ö-Ü"}'
```

---

For other renderers you have to check their documentation.